# I have a nested json that I want to run a for loop to only match the key that is different

Tags: python, json, for-loop, nested

Hello Appreciate any help for a rookies first question on stack OF OF = oh &$*#. Yes in way over my head but am persistent.
Apologies My questions are missing proper syntax for Python grammar, I have no doubt.

1. The json below has two types a light and a switch several lights and switches would be in the json.
2. The for loop below gives me all lights and switches.
3. I want to be able to have the result of two for loops one to print just the switches and the other just the lights based on the nested value of devices["devId"]["dps"]["20"] for lights and devices["devId"]["dps"]["1"] for switches.
4. Please, how would I look at the json for all and have it separate for each light and switch with two for loops.
5. Also a way to count each as switch_1, switch_2, etc... light_1, light_2 etc...
   totalnum = len(data['devices'])
   for i in range(1, totalnum):
   item['address'] = 'switch_{}'.format(i)

Thank You for Your Valuable Time!

### json sample of each Device:

```
"devices": [
    {
        "name": "Office Light",
        "ip": "192.168.1.147",
        "ver": "3.3",
        "id": "######################",
        "key": "################",  
        "devId": {
            "dps": {
                "20": true,
                "21": "white",
                "22": 109,
                "23": 1000,
                "24": "01050252010e",
                "25": "020d0d00000000000000001903e8",
                "26": 0
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Switch Family Room Sconces",
        "ip": "192.168.1.155",
        "ver": "3.3",
        "id": "####################",
        "key": "################",
        "devId": {
            "devId": "017743508caab5f385a7",
            "dps": {
                "1": false,
                "9": 0
            }
        }
    }
 ]
```

}

### For loop for all devices:

```
for item in data["devices"]:
    name = item["name"]
    print(name)
    id = item["id"]
    print(id)
    ip = item["ip"]
    print(ip)
    key = item["key"]
    print(key)
    ver = item["ver"]
    print(ver)
```

### For loop result:

```
Office Light
ebfc16d57ed374932cjqfk
192.168.1.147
805217605357161b
3.3
Switch Family Room Sconces
017743508caab5f385a7
192.168.1.155
7b8f2415ac96dfea
3.3
```

Comment: maybe add your expected output as your requirements are slightly difficult to understand, otherwise all elements were provided which is good for a first question

Comment: Does it need to return/print in the order in the json? Or can you do all lights first, and all switches second?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Thank You so much for the direction to add the outcome of what is expected! I will include this on any future questions. 
Very Helpful!
 Thank You for Your Time!

Comment: @chitown88, 
They come in randomly when polled so this that you have sent looks very close for what I am trying to achieve! After this sorting each type is then sent out separately to be added as a node in an automation program to a separate script, one for lights and one for switches. I will play with this over the weekend and get back to you if I have resolved my issue. 
Thank You So Very Much!
Highest Regards!

Comment: @chitown88,
I am once again stuck on this as the code was changed and the json imported is a little different. I will add what is going on below as it is close to this problem you solved a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

Few ways to go about it. You can convert the json to a dataframe, then just filter out from there:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np

jsonData = '''{"devices": [
    {
        "name": "Office Light",
        "ip": "192.168.1.147",
        "ver": "3.3",
        "id": "######################",
        "key": "################",  
        "devId": {
            "dps": {
                "20": true,
                "21": "white",
                "22": 109,
                "23": 1000,
                "24": "01050252010e",
                "25": "020d0d00000000000000001903e8",
                "26": 0
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Switch Family Room Sconces",
        "ip": "192.168.1.155",
        "ver": "3.3",
        "id": "####################",
        "key": "################",
        "devId": {
            "devId": "017743508caab5f385a7",
            "dps": {
                "1": false,
                "9": 0
            }
        }
    }
 ]
}'''

jsonData = json.loads(jsonData)
df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData['devices'])
df = df.fillna(-1)


df['type'] = None
df['type'] = np.where(df['devId.dps.20'] != -1, 'light', df['type'])
df['type'] = np.where(df['devId.dps.1'] != -1, 'switch', df['type'])


lights = df[df['type'] == 'light'].reset_index(drop=True)                    
switches = df[df['type'] == 'switch'].reset_index(drop=True)  


device_list = [lights, switches]
for device in device_list:
    for idx, row in device.iterrows():
        name = row['name']
        ip = row['ip']
        key = row['key']
        ver = row['ver']
        type_num = row['type'] + '_%s' %(idx+1)
        
        print('{name}\n{ip}\n{key}\n{ver}\n{type_num}\n'.format(name=name, 
                                                                      ip=ip,
                                                                      key=key,ver=ver,
                                                                      type_num=type_num))
```

**Output:**

```
Office Light
192.168.1.147
################
3.3
light_1

Switch Family Room Sconces
192.168.1.155
################
3.3
switch_1
```