# How can I separate LED lights and Switches in a Pandas DataFrame using JSON and numpy?

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, numpy, for-loop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlcDl.png)I had this problem a year ago and once again need help with Pandas. Embarrassingly having the same problem as last year as an api has been updated.

Original Question Here - [I have a nested json that I want to run a for loop to only match the key that is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69566715/i-have-a-nested-json-that-i-want-to-run-a-for-loop-to-only-match-the-key-that-is)

I have a json with two types of devices, a Switch and an LED light.
Now i need to differentiate between the two and had it before the imported json had its structure changed.

My json is received like this with 11 devices, so [19 rows x 11 columns]:

```
`{
 "192.168.1.102": {
        "ip": "192.168.1.102",
        "gwId": "eb7ac0fbe689ca95f7dxxk",
        "active": 2,
        "encrypt": true,
        "productKey": "keya4gvchmtapm8n",
        "version": "3.3",
        "name": "Switch Garage Overhead",
        "key": "449ebc60812eb8bb",
        "mac": "38:1f:8d:18:5e:a2",
        "id": "eb7ac0fbe689ca95f7dxxk",
        "ability": 0,
        "token": "",
        "wf_cfg": "",
        "dev_type": "default",
        "err": "",
        "type": "default",
        "dps": {
            "dps": {
                "1": true,
                "9": 0,
                "38": "off",
                "40": "relay",
                "41": false,
                "42": "",
                "43": "",
                "44": ""
            }
        },
        "origin": "broadcast"
    },
    "192.168.1.147": {
        "ip": "192.168.1.147",
        "gwId": "ebfc16d57ed374932cjqfk",
        "active": 2,
        "encrypt": true,
        "productKey": "keypcvqhw97kqy4h",
        "version": "3.3",
        "name": "LED Office",
        "key": "805217605357161b",
        "mac": "84:e3:42:1a:96:35",
        "id": "ebfc16d57ed374932cjqfk",
        "ability": 0,
        "token": "",
        "wf_cfg": "",
        "dev_type": "default",
        "err": "",
        "type": "default",
        "dps": {
            "dps": {
                "20": false,
                "21": "white",
                "22": 10,
                "23": 1000,
                "24": "00180120038d",
                "25": "020d0d00000000000000001903e8",
                "26": 0
            }
        },
        "origin": "broadcast"
    }
}
`
```

Now i again want to be able to separate each based on "dps" 20 = LED and 1 = Switch.

My test Code:

```
import tinytuya
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

f = open('snapshot.json',)
devices = json.load(f)
list = json.dumps(devices, indent=4)
print(list)

df = pd.DataFrame(devices)
# df = pd.json_normalize(devices)
df.to_dict()
df = df.fillna(-1)
print('\n')
print('devices')
print(df)

# Separation of led's and switches here
df['type'] = None
try:
    df['type'] = np.where(
        df['dps.20'] != -1, 'light', df['type'])
except:
    pass
try:
    df['type'] = np.where(
        df['dps.dps.1'] != -1, 'switch', df['type'])
except:
    pass


lights = df[df['type'] == 'light'].reset_index(drop=True)
print("Lights {}".format(str(lights)))
switches = df[df['type'] == 'switch'].reset_index(drop=True)
print("switches {}".format(str(switches)))

# Lights
device_list = [lights]
for device in device_list:
    for idx, row in device.iterrows():
        name = row['name']
        id = row['gwId']
        id_new = id
        ip = row['ip']
        key = row['key']
        ver = row['ver']
        # id_new = id
        address = row['type'] + '_%s' % (idx+1)
        print('{name}\n{id_new}\n{ip}\n{key}\n{ver}\n{address}\n'.format(
            name=name, id_new=id_new, ip=ip, key=key, ver=ver, address=address,))

# Switches
device_list = [switches]
for device in device_list:
    for idx, row in device.iterrows():
        name = row['name']
        id = row['id']
        id_new = id
        ip = row['ip']
        key = row['key']
        ver = row['ver']
        # id_new = id
        address = row['type'] + '_%s' % (idx+1)
        print('{name}\n{id_new}\n{ip}\n{key}\n{ver}\n{address}\n'.format(
            name=name, id_new=id_new, ip=ip, key=key, ver=ver, address=address,))
        # node = tuya_switch_node.SwitchNode(
        #    self.poly, self.address, address, name, id_new, ip, key)
        # self.poly.addNode(node)
        # self.wait_for_node_event()

print("Done Appending and sorting")
```

CODE Run Result:
Please see image attached.

So i want to be able to have switches and LED's separated by "dps" row value.

```
LED Garage
ebfd4f4263bb769d99zjkq
192.168.1.148
ec0b2b581a246eab
3.3
light_3

Switch Garden Outside
017743508caab5f385a7
192.168.1.146
2bc2d5aef80f3aee
3.3
switch_1
```

Thank You for any help I definitely appreciate it!

Tried re-writing code to no avail also several help and tutorials on Pandas. Must be something simple because I am stumped.

Wrote test code to sort json to separate switches from Led's within the json file with Pandas. Seperation based on row "dps".

Result attached and code above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it would be simpler to just loop through the data in plain python?

You can check for the existence of `1` or `20` as a key and append to either the LED or SWITCH list if desired.

```
LEDS = []
SWITCHES = []

for device in data.values():
   name = device["name"]
   ip = device["ip"]
   print(f"{name=}")
   print(f"{ip=}")
   if "1" in device["dps"]["dps"]:
      print("SWITCH")
   elif "20" in device["dps"]["dps"]:
      print("LED")
   else:
      print("OTHER")
```

```
name='Switch Garage Overhead'
ip='192.168.1.102'
SWITCH
name='LED Office'
ip='192.168.1.147'
LED
```

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot because the name is a variable that a customer puts in so they will not always be identified that way. So i need to use the dps data. Thank you for your suggestion. I will look into this and see if it is solid for what i am trying to do! Really appreciate your fast feedback!

Comment: What name? I'm not sure I follow, the code example given checks the dps data?

Comment: I am just back at home and working on it! Sorry @jqurious i misread your reply the first time! This should work fine and is a much simpler solution! Thank You i will get back to you with a conclusion, if i figure it out!

Comment: Hello @ jqurious, this works fine in a test. I will get back with the code later. Thank You for Your Time!

Comment: Hello @qurious, It works to separate different types LED's and Switches! Thank you and Daaa! Now the reason I used Pandas was to have it identify each instance of LED or Switch as LED_1 - through all LED's and SWITCH_1 through all switches. So a result name='Switch Garage Overhead'
ip='192.168.1.116'
SWITCH_1
ip='192.168.1.102'
SWITCH_2
name='LED Office'
ip='192.168.1.147'
LED_1
name='LED Garage'
ip='192.168.1.147'
LED_2   Again I am stumped on how to add a for or while loop to do this for each instance found.

Comment: If you are `.append()`ing the items into their own lists, you can use `len(LEDS) + 1` for example to get that number. Or if you're processing the lists later, a common way to get a counter/index is to use `.enumerate()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import pandas as pd

f = open('snapshot.json',)
devices = json.load(f)

# Normalize the dictionary to a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(devices).T

# Add a new 'device_type' column based on the 'dps' column
df['type'] = df['dps'].apply(lambda x: 'switch' if '1' in x['dps'] else ('light' if '20' in x['dps'] else 'Unknown'))

switches = df[df['type'] == 'switch'].reset_index(drop=True) 
lights = df[df['type'] == 'light'].reset_index(drop=True)  


for table in [switches, lights]:
    for idx, row in table.iterrows():
        name = row['name']
        id = row['id']
        id_new = id
        ip = row['ip']
        key = row['key']
        ver = row['version']
        # id_new = id
        address = f"{row['type']}_{idx+1}"
        print('{name}\n{id_new}\n{ip}\n{key}\n{ver}\n{address}\n'.format(
            name=name, id_new=id_new, ip=ip, key=key, ver=ver, address=address,))
```

**Output:**

```
Switch Garage Overhead
eb7ac0fbe689ca95f7dxxk
192.168.1.102
449ebc60812eb8bb
3.3
switch_1

LED Office
ebfc16d57ed374932cjqfk
192.168.1.147
805217605357161b
3.3
light_1
```